# Does the quality filter work?

Tags: bug, quality-filter

Just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190231/how-can-we-found-difference-betweeen-highest-value-and-lowest-value-from-column) which only contains 32 characters in a single sentence.

I thought a quality filter would prevent such posts. Is it turned off?

For the benefit of <10k, here's the content of the post:

> #### how can we found difference betweeen highest value and lowest value from column in mysql tables
>
> please help me with the sql code

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664177/salary-define-how):

> #### salary define how?
>
> **strong text**[enter image description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190231/how-can-we-found-difference-betweeen-highest-value-and-lowest-value-from-column)

[And another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586552/how-to-get-first-1mb-rows-in-mysql):

> #### How to get first 1mb rows in mysql?
>
> How to get first 1mb rows in mysql?

Comment: Sure it works, but computers are not infallible?

Comment: computer-quality-filter failed, but human-quality-filter succeed :  question was "on hold" in 2 minutes (even before you had time to post this one) and deleted in 15 minutes.

Comment: This is still a fair question. This is exactly the kind of bad content the quality filter is supposed to catch, after all.

Comment: I would say it failed if it appeared in anyones home/interesting/recommended page, or it didn't appeared in the LQRQ, otherwise I would say The System Works™

Comment: This is a very poor question that is unanswerable.  It asks if the filter is turned on but actually wants to discuss how it works.  Full-well knowing that the devs are not going to reveal that info, it will be abused to work around it.  Why did this question not get filtered?  Well, if a high rep SO user can't detect a bad question then how is a machine supposed to pull it off?

Comment: @HansPassant: Actually I only want to know if it is turned on or has changed currently. I marked this as bug and not as a discussion.